# Photoshop Scripting JavaScript loop through layers problem

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I have a script that does the following:

loops through layers,
saves each layer in a separate folder (name of folder same as layer name)
saved layer images have names "nameofthedocument, nameofthelayer.png"

Now I wanted to add text item on top of those layers while they are saving as separate pngs so that for gods sake you don't have to always look at the file name but instead there would be text in the PNG image rasterized and says "nameofthelayer" variable.

So for each layer of course different text should be inserted in the image.

i encountered weird problems once I tried to do that what seamigly looked easy.

HEre is the link with a video and an explanation of the code as well as what I did and why it messed up the script.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h2KAiEuruLY_PQ2JVhQAwINDYPvk9xHS?usp=sharing

Thank you folks, please help me out
Code, image and video explanation is all available in the link

CODE:

```
// NAME: 
//  SaveLayers

// DESCRIPTION: 
//  Saves each layer in the active document to a PNG or JPG file named after the layer. 
//  These files will be created in the current document folder.

// REQUIRES: 
//  Adobe Photoshop CS2 or higher

// VERSIONS:
//  27 March 2013 by Robin Parmar (robin@robinparmar.com)
//      preferences stored in object
//      auto-increment file names to prevent collisions
//      properly handles layer groups
//      header added
//      code comments added
//      main() now has error catcher
//      counts number of layers
//      many little code improvements

//  26 Sept 2012 by Johannes on stackexchange
//      original version

// enable double-clicking from Finder/Explorer (CS2 and higher)
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();


//alert(activeDocument.name);

function main() {
    // two quick checks
    if(!okDocument()) {
        alert("Document must be saved and be a layered PSD.");
        return; 
    }

    var len = activeDocument.layers.length;
   
    // user preferences
    prefs = new Object();
    prefs.fileType = "";
    prefs.fileQuality = 0;
    prefs.filePath = app.activeDocument.path;
    prefs.count = 0;

      
    saveLayers(activeDocument);
    //toggleVisibility(activeDocument);
    
}

function saveLayers(ref) {
    var len = ref.layers.length;

    // rename layers top to bottom
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var layer = ref.layers[i];
 
        if (layer.typename == 'LayerSet') {
            // recurse if current layer is a group
            saveLayers(layer);
        } else {
            // otherwise make sure the layer is visible and save it
            layer.visible = true;
            saveImage(layer.name);
            layer.visible = false;
        }
    }
}


function getNameWithoutExtension(nameWithExt) {
    var nameWithoutExtension = nameWithExt;
    return nameWithoutExtension.split(".")[0];
}

function saveImage(layerName) {
    var f = new Folder("D:/Process/0/"+layerName);  
    f.create();
    
    
    
    



//////////////// BROKEN PART I ADDED

    
    #target photoshop
// Current layer name as text layer
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myRulers = app.preferences.rulerUnits
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var OriginalLayerName = myDoc.activeLayer.name
var myLayerName = myDoc.activeLayer.name + "text";
var myLayerText = myDoc.artLayers.add()
myLayerText.kind = LayerKind.TEXT
var myText = myLayerText.textItem
myColor = new SolidColor
myColor.rgb.red = 255
myColor.rgb.green = 0
myColor.rgb.blue = 0
myLayerText.textItem.color = myColor
myText.position = [0,20] // Upper Left
myText.justification = Justification.LEFT
myText.size = 12
myText.contents = myLayerName
myLayerText.name = myLayerName // Or add a fixed string in quotes i.e. 'My Great Layer Name!'
app.preferences.rulerUnits = myRulers

//////////////////////////////END OF THE BROKN PART


    
    
    //var handle = generateName(f.path + "/",layerName, ".png");
    //alert(handle);
    var handle = getUniqueName(prefs.filePath + "/"+ layerName +"/"+ getNameWithoutExtension(activeDocument.name) + ", " + layerName);
    //alert(handle);
    prefs.count++;
    
    if(prefs.fileType=="PNG") {
        SavePNG(handle); 
    } else {
        SaveJPEG(handle); 
    }
}

function getUniqueName(fileroot) { 
    // form a full file name
    // if the file name exists, a numeric suffix will be added to disambiguate
    
    var filename = fileroot;
    for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
        var handle = File(filename + "." + prefs.fileType); 
        if(handle.exists) {
            filename = fileroot + "-" + padder(i, 3);
        } else {
            return handle; 
        }
    }
}



function padder(input, padLength) {
    // pad the input with zeroes up to indicated length
    var result = (new Array(padLength + 1 - input.toString().length)).join('0') + input;
    return result;
}

function SavePNG(saveFile) { 
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); 
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
} 

function SaveJPEG(saveFile) {
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); 
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
} 







   // file type
    var saveOpt = [];
    saveOpt[0] = "PNG"; 
    saveOpt[1] = "PNG"; 
    



    // png type
    var pngtypeOpt = [1];
    pngtypeOpt[0]=24;
    pngtypeOpt[1]=24;






function okDocument() {
     // check that we have a valid document

    if (!documents.length) return false;

    var thisDoc = app.activeDocument; 
    var fileExt = decodeURI(thisDoc.name).replace(/^.*\./,''); 
    return fileExt.toLowerCase() == 'psd'
}

function wrapper() {
    function showError(err) {
        alert(err + ': on line ' + err.line, 'Script Error', true);
    }

    try {
        // suspend history for CS3 or higher
        if (parseInt(version, 10) >= 10) {
            activeDocument.suspendHistory('Save Layers', 'main()');
        } else {
            main();
        }
    } catch(e) {
        // report errors unless the user cancelled
        if (e.number != 8007) showError(e);
    }
}


function generateName(filePath, layerName, ext) {
    var generatedName = app.activeDocument.name;
    var generatedName = generatedName.split(".")[0];
    generatedName = generatedName + ", " + layerName;
    return filePath + generatedName + ext;
}


wrapper();
```

Comment: I did I just did it